# Search database for specific tags

Tags: mysql

I have an image table with a column called `tags`. A typical entry would look like this:

```
id    link    tags
-------------------
1     [link]  funny,not-cool,work
```

I have a search page where users can enter tags to search for images. They could enter any amount of tags separated by a comma

```
Search: funny, fall, fail
```

Question is, what is the best way to search the database for these tags? Would a simple `LIKE` be it? I know it may have been more ideal to add each tag in a different table and not have them comma separated so if I need to change the way the tags work I will.

Comment: i think u answered your own questions. separate rows and not a like. (id, link) in 1 table, and (id, tag) in another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be better do have multiple tables here. The first table would be called `images` and just `id` and `link`. The second table would be called `tags` with each row being one specific tag such say columns `id` and `tag`. The third table would be a join table called something like `imagetags` with columns `id`, `image`, and `tag`. The `image` column in `imagetags` would be a foreign key to `images` and the `tag` column would be a foreign key to `tags`.

Using your example search the SQL would be something like:

```
SELECT images.link 
FROM images 
JOIN imagetags on images.id = imagetags.image
JOIN tags on tags.id = imagetags.tag
WHERE tags.tag in ('funny','fall','fail')
```